# Can't find SDK and AVD Manager

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

This is my first step in the direction of android development so apologise for any silly question.

I have used windows installer to install the Android SDK Manager. Post installation, this is how my start menu looks like.

[image: Start Menu]

And this is how the SDK Manager looks like:

[image: SDK Manager]

When I try to use Eclipse pluggin, I get the following error.

> [2012-01-13 16:29:10 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

So I thought maybe I should update the SDK manager but SDK Manager update does nothing at all.

I searched through the forums and documentation. People keep saying that I should use the SDK and AVD Manager. I just can't find any tool by that name. Is that a seperate installation? I can find an SDK manager and a seperate AVD manager and doesn't look anything like the screenshots see in forums/documentation. Maybe I am using the wrong version! I downloaded the SDK from the [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

---

### UPDATE 1: 13 Jan 2012

Here is something more I figured. When I try to update using my SDK manager, this is what I see in the log:

```
Fetching http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml, reason: Connection to http://dl-ssl.google.com refused
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml
Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml, reason: Connection to http://dl-ssl.google.com refused
Fetching URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml, reason: Connection to http://dl-ssl.google.com refused
Fetching URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
```

For some reason, connection to http://dl-ssl.google.com is being refused and maybe that's why I am unable to update anything.

---

### UPDATE 2: 16 January 2012

Okay I haven't got any response, I am going to write down everything I am doing before I forget. Maybe it will be useful for someone else...

I was facing many problems while configuring the environment for Android development. I have sorted solution for couple of issues so far. Maybe I will sort out the others soon!

**Environment Used:**
Windows XP 32 bit
Eclipse Helios

**Problem 1:**
Could not find SDK and AVD Manager component after installing Android SDK.

**Solution to Problem 1**
Although there is no proper documentation, it took a while for me to understand that the latest version of Android SDK has seperated SDK from AVD Management. So once you install Android SDK, expect to see two components - 1) SDK Manager, 2) AVD Manager. I am not sure what sort of features have changed from previous version, but if you are into android development for the first time, this change could drive you nuts as all documents speak based on the previous versions - bad GOOGLE!

**Problem 2**
During installation of SDK, the .exe for windows is unable to detect JDK.

**Solution to Problem 2**
Again, older documents and forum posts seem to say that hitting the back and then hitting next once again should solve the problem. Not so with the latest version. Google has come up with a funny work around to beat this defect. Now you have a small button called *"Report Error"*. Click that and the next button will be enabled. This should let you proceed with the installation

**Problem 3:**
Installing the Eclipse ADT plugin causes the following error

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.0.20100617-0521 (epp.package.jee 1.3.0.20100617-0521)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Hierarchy Viewer 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
    To: org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.0.20100617-0521 (epp.package.jee 1.3.0.20100617-0521)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.3.0.20100617-0521]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.3.0.20100617-0521 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.3.0.20100617-0521)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.0.v20100602-9gF78GpqFt6trOGhL60z0oEx3fz-JKNwxPY]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.0.v20100602-9gF78GpqFt6trOGhL60z0oEx3fz-JKNwxPY (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.0.v20100602-9gF78GpqFt6trOGhL60z0oEx3fz-JKNwxPY)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.0.v20100519-9OArFKvFtsd7WLUKh-DcYTS]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.0.v20100519-9OArFKvFtsd7WLUKh-DcYTS (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.0.v20100519-9OArFKvFtsd7WLUKh-DcYTS)
    To: org.eclipse.ui [3.6.0.I20100603-1100]
```

**Solution to Problem 3**
This is caused because Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers is an older version. So in Eclipse, go to Help >> Update Softwares. This would list the latest Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developer. Install it. Then repeat the steps to install Android ADT pluggin. This solved the problem for me.

**Problem 4:**
When you open eclipse after installing the ADT pluggin, the following error appears:
**[2012-01-16 16:00:10 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe**

**Solution for Problem 4:**
This issue has been fixed with the help extended by Nandeesh (see below comments). I download the platform-tools directory from the following location (http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r10-windows.zip) and unzipped it under platform-tools directory in my installation directory. This removed the error from Eclipse ADT.

**Problem 5:**
Following error occurs when I refresh using SDK manager

```
Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml, reason: Connection to http://dl-ssl.google.com refused
```

Partial solution to Problem 5:
I am stuck with this problem and I haven't found a solution so far. Here is what I have learnt.

All the post on this error claim that this has to do with proxy settings. This is what I did:
I found out my proxy setting by going to my Internet Explorer >> Internet Options >> Connections >> Lan Settings. Copied the proxy details and set it up in Eclipse >> Windows >> Preferences >> General >> Network Connections. After this I went to SDK manager >> Tools >> Options  and entered proxy details in the HTTP Proxy server Box and checked the force https option. Tried refreshing - no luck. Then getting desperate, I have tried all combinations of Proxy and force https. Nothing seems to work. So, as per suggestion made by Nandeesh (refer comments below), I have started downloading the files directly based on the repository.xml found here ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml. So far so good.

**Problem 6:**
Unable to detect target SDK in eclipse ADT

**Solution for Problem 6:**
This is what I did. Downloaded the latest Eclipse. I now use Eclipse Indigo. Then I checked the directory structure of the SDK installed. I installed it under C:/Android/android-sdk. Avoid any spaces in the file path (that could be causing the issue). The Android/android-sdk directory should contain the following directories - platforms, platform-tools, tools, add-ons. Inside the platforms directory I see android-4.0.3 directory. This directory should have the version number as part of the directory name. If you don't see this directory, download the suitable platform from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/. The version you should be using depends on your environment. The list of all directory is available in this XML http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml. Download the corresponding platform an unzip the entire contents into C:/Android/android-sdk/platforms. Also download the corresponding platform-tools and unzip the entire contents into platform-tools directory. Restart eclipse. The SDK should be automatically detected. If not, go to Windows >> Preference >> Android and set the SDK installation directory. Hit apply and it should list the available targets. NOTE that the targets will be list if and only if the SDK installation is correct. So ensure that the platforms directory inside the SDK installation is correct.

**Problem 7**
I am seeing this when I open eclipse
[image]

No idea what went wrong. Again suspecting that this is because I manually copied the files :(

**Solution to Problem 7:**
Read solution to Problem 6. This would solve problem 7 also. The only thing that is important is that make sure your SDK is installed properly. If not manually copy the appropriate platforms and platform-tools and try once again. Ensure the structure of the files are proper and that files names do not have a space.

Having done all of this, I can now say that I have set up my environment and now I ready to code! This issue is RESOLVED :)

Comment: Have you installed the Android SDK Platform-tools using the SDK Manager you installed? Also, have you set your `PATH` environment variable to point to the location of the `platform-tools` directory in your Android SDK installation?

Comment: did you check C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe  this path? is adb.exe present at that location? older versions of sdk used to have adb.exe at tools  folder.

Comment: If you are using a 64-Bit windows Android SDK maybe installed on Program Files(x86)

Comment: I do not see a 'platform-tools' directory in the installation path. Instead, I see the 'adb_has_moved.txt' following under the tools directory. The content of the file says : "If you don't see this directory in your SDK,
launch the SDK and AVD Manager (execute the android tool)
and install "Android SDK Platform-tools"". I have no idea what this SDK and AVD Manager is and I have no idea how to install install 'Android SDK Platform-tools'. Is SDK and AVD Manager = SDK Manager? If yes, how do I install Adroid SDK Platform tools? The only Install button in my SDK Manager is disabled!

Comment: All, please read the update to my actual question. Any idea of why this could be? Should I be pointing to some other URL?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist any idea on this?

Comment: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r10-windows.zip  Download this zip and unzip to platform-tools folder in android-sdk folder

Comment: @nandeesh this solved the platform tools issue but I am not able to see any target SDKs under Eclipse >> Windows >> Preferences >> Android. Target SDKs are not being recognized. Am I missing something?

Comment: then you are missing more folders :) . I guess you have to download from link http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.3.3_r02-linux.zip and paste it in platforms folder. You can get more by reading the http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml
All the folders are picked from this xml so you need to download the files.

Comment: Thank you @nandeesh but that doesn't seem to help. I have copied all the missing folders but still eclipse wouldn't pick up the SDK. I wonder if I can manually set up eclipse to pick up this. I am going to search for configuration files now. Do let me know if I could be missing something else.

Comment: @nandeesh I am encountering problems after problems. Now I get an error when I open the eclipse and I am still not able to see the SDK target. The error reads "Unable to get the required ADT version from SDK. The Android Development Toolkit may not work properl"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May or may not still be an issue - but I was unable to use a path with a space in the name ("Program Files" was the culprit).  I believe this is fixed in the current release, but it is worth a try to fix your problem.

Comment: No luck. I tried it but doesn't work anyway. I still get the error  "Unable to get the required ADT version from SDK. The Android Development Toolkit may not work properly" and the target SDK doesn't show itself

Comment: have you downloaded and installed the target SDK?  That might be the problem, they are large downloads and you may not have installed it...

Comment: Do you have the URL for downloading the target SDK?

Comment: That should be handled by the SDK Manager.  I don't think you should have to manually point to a URL to download it.  It's in the "Available Packages" menu option.

Comment: My SDK Manager is screwed! It keeps saying that connection to google is refused. Possibly because of a firewall. That's why I have been manaully updating the tools, platform and platform-tools directory in SDK manager.

Comment: That's likely your problem then.  Make sure your environment is able to access the proper directories and your problem should go away.  Also make sure your antivirus/firewall is not blocking google's ssl socket.

Comment: I have no idea of how to make my SDK access the proper directories. I have been trying to do it for the past couple of days. No one seems to have the answer. Looks like I have to give up Android development. Not sure if it is even worth spending 3 days to just set up the environment!!! :(

Comment: @SJoe my recommendation is to start from the beginning.  Uninstall everything and follow the instructions on developer.google.com to the letter.  I've set up an Android environment in 15 minutes before, I am not sure why you are having so many issues :(

Comment: Can you confirm which version you have used?
I have installed and reinstalled atleast 20 times :)

Comment: I have the latest tools on my personal and work PC, ADT version 9.

Comment: You do have Eclipse pointing to the android folder in the Android menu for IDE options, right?  That might be the issue you are having.

Comment: Ok I am going to try with Eclipse Indigo. Maybe Helios is the problem. ADT and SDK are latest versions, only that I have had to do some manual downloading of tools and platform tools.

Comment: Yes, I use Eclipse Indigo.  Never had any problems, other than the one I mentioned.

Comment: The issue is fixed!!! Yippeee! I will explain the mistake I did tomorrow but for now, my environment is ready and atlast I can code!

Comment: I installed Eclipse Indigo. While reinstalling, I realized I could be wrong in one of the things. I was manually downloading the platform and platform-tools directories. I downloaded the following platform  http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-15_r01.zip. I unziped it and instead of placing the whole content into my platform folder, I copied the contents within the android-4.0.3. That was the mistake. The directory android-4.0.3 is important as this is what suggests the version number to the ADT plugin. Thank you so much for helping me narrow down the issue. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

problem 4: When you open eclipse after installing the ADT pluggin, the following error appears: [2012-01-16 16:00:10 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

Solution:

I had the same problem with my eclipse Juno.
then i found that the platform-tools got corrupted.
i deleted the corrupted file from sdk manager and re-installed it.
Now i dint find any error messages.

Hope this would help you!!

Answer (score 0):

for **problem 5** :

The problem is your network ofcourse. 
Use a **moderm** instead of a LAN and this will work perfectly. 
But if you are using a LAN then ask your network administrator to help you with this.